# PHP Get values from CSV into an array

Tags: php, arrays, csv, multidimensional-array

I have the following csv file:

```
9 carat gold,11.87
18 carat gold,23.73
Silver,0.49
Platinum,27.52
```

I would like to put this in a Multidimensional Array but i have no idea how to.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
$csv = file_get_contents($file);
$data = explode(PHP_EOL, $csv);
$arr = array();
foreach ($data as $entry) {
    $arr[] = str_getcsv($entry);
}
print_r($arr);
```

You can go through [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) for more details about str_getcsv function

Answer (score 0):

You can use **fgetcsv** to parse a CSV file without having to worry about parsing it yourself.

Example from PHP Manual:

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use fgetcsv to read a csv file open with fopen.